# Any real use case for dynamic polymorphism other than Animals and Shapes?

Tags: oop, polymorphism

I am desperately trying to find good useful examples of dynamic polymorphism that are not:

- Shapes with triangles, circles and squares
- Car with models
- Animals with dogs and cats

I looked at over 20 different books and 50 websites devoted to OOP programming and I only find these abovementioned examples, but never any real use case which is not *just* a real-life analogy. I am looking for something that really provides a design advantage in terms of readability and complexity. When I find real use cases, such as parsing tokens or storage containers I realize you don't need dynamic polymorphism and often it is not implemented in such a way. Even in [CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) where everything inherits from the `type` class, the code behind the scenes is pure C code without with few dynamic polymorphismscases.

If I want to teach polymorphism and particularly `override` and `virtual` in C++. What real code examples can I use? Or what popular projects can I use as reference?

Comment: And C behind the scenes is just 0s and 1s, but from that we can't conclude that programming languages have no real use cases. So the fact, that python uses something else in a lower level layer is not an argument.

Comment: I don't have experience with c++, but I can give you an example from c# that we use a lot: when you have an object that contains sensitive data, you can override the moethod ToString() and mask the sensitive data. Please note that polymorphism doesn't mean only overriding methods. It also means the usage of interfaces (thus helping you with the open-close principle).

Comment: You can find associations with the `Banking` domain

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/375639/how-is-polymorphism-used-in-the-real-world

Comment: @jaco0646 Not very convincing :(